# Applying a function to a small dataframe: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be broadcast

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply an API result to two columns.

My dummy dataframe below. unfortunately this is not very reproducable, as I'm using an API with key and password... this is just to give you an idea of the dimensions.

But I hope maybe somebody can spot an obvious problem.

I am pinging mobile numbers using an API, and recording the information to the columns `phone_ping` and `phone_reason` (whether they are active/inactive & other info)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=range(0, 4))

df['name'] = ['Jim Bob', 'Joe Bloggs', 'Chuck Norris', 'Jane Doe']
df['mobile'] = ['2222588', '+352654600810', pd.np.nan, '+123456']

print(df)

           name         mobile phone_ping phone_reason
0       Jim Bob        2222588        NaN          NaN
1    Joe Bloggs  +352654600810        NaN          NaN
2  Chuck Norris            NaN        NaN          NaN
3      Jane Doe        +123456        NaN          NaN
```

So the API checks the phone number, and returns a message such as `success` along with another message such as `deliverable`. These are the two columns `phone_ping` and `phone_reason` that I am filling.

Function below to apply to the df:

```
def pingmobile(phone):

    # if both phone and email are present
    if pd.notnull(phone):

        # Perform GET request
        response = requests.get(url).json()

        # record status and message
        status = response['status']
        message = response['error_text']

        # return it to my two columns
        return pd.DataFrame([(status,message)])

     else:
        # if there is no phone number, just return Nan
        return pd.DataFrame([(pd.np.nan,pd.np.nan)])
```

Applying the function, which should return the data to columns `['phone_ping','phone_reason']`:

```
df.loc[:,['phone_ping','phone_reason']] = df.loc[:,'mobile'].apply(lambda x: pingmobile(x))
```

Expected results:

```
           name         mobile phone_ping phone_reason
0       Jim Bob        2222588        Fail         Invalid Number
1    Joe Bloggs  +352654600810        Success      Deliverable
2  Chuck Norris            NaN        NaN          NaN
3      Jane Doe        +123456        Fail         Invalid Number
```

Error code:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-318-7e506c1da8e2> in <module>
----> 1 df.loc[:,['phone_ping','phone_reason']] = df.loc[:,'mobile'].apply(lambda x: pingmobile(x))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    200             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    201         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 202         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    203 
    204     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
    577             # actually do the set
    578             self.obj._consolidate_inplace()
--> 579             self.obj._data = self.obj._data.setitem(indexer=indexer, value=value)
    580             self.obj._maybe_update_cacher(clear=True)
    581 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in setitem(self, **kwargs)
    558 
    559     def setitem(self, **kwargs):
--> 560         return self.apply("setitem", **kwargs)
    561 
    562     def putmask(self, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    436                     kwargs[k] = obj.reindex(b_items, axis=axis, copy=align_copy)
    437 
--> 438             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    439             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    440 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in setitem(self, indexer, value)
    936         # set
    937         else:
--> 938             values[indexer] = value
    939 
    940         # coerce and try to infer the dtypes of the result

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to return a `Series` instead of a `DataFrame`:

```
def pingmobile(phone):
    if pd.notnull(phone):
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        status = response['status']
        message = response['error_text']

        return pd.Series({"status": response["status"],
                          "message": response["error_text"]})

    return pd.Series({"status": pd.np.nan,
                      "message": pd.np.nan})
```

Then, just apply your function:

```
df[["phone_ping", "phone_reason"]] = df.mobile.apply(pingmobile)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! But how did it work? The returned series has two rows, with indexes `status` and `message`. I am only returning it to one row: `df[["phone_ping", "phone_reason"]]`. How do two rows & one column turn into one row & two columns?

Comment: With `apply`, every cell in `mobile` is turned into the value that `pingmobile` returns (a series). And a series in a series is a dataframe; the index if the inner series (`status` and `response`) are the columns of the returned dataframe. Try calling `print(df.mobile.apply(pingmobile))`. In the end of course, we assign our result to `df`, and name `status` `phone_ping` and `message` `phone_reason`.